# Getting the title of the next comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

At the bottom of my comments show page I have a link to the next comment. The problem is I am unable to get the title of the next comment.

Here is the function in the Comment model:

```
def next
  post.comments.where("id > ?", id).order("id ASC").first
end
```

Here is the comments controller:

```
def show 
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = Comment.find params[:id]
  @commentnext = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
end
```

and here is the link:

```
<%= link_to (???), post_comment_path(@post, @commentnext.next) %>
```

I have tried:

```
<%= link_to "#{@comment.title}", post_comment_path(@post, @commentnext.next) %>
```

but that gives me the title of the comment I am on.

Comment: where the `next` method placed? And why you don't use link text `@commentnext.title`? Probably i can't properly understand a question.

Comment: In the comments model

Comment: I guess you mistyped. Link text should be like `"#{@commentnext.title}"` or `"#{@commentnext.next.title}"` according to your question. Seems like you try to use title of previous comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `@commentnext.next` is the "next comment" you're referring to, `@commentnext.next.title` would presumable give you the title of the next comment.

```
<%= link_to @commentnext.next.title, post_comment_path(@post, @commentnext.next) %>
```

If `@commentnext.next` returns an id, use the following in your controller:

```
def show 
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = Comment.find params[:id]
  @commentnext = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
  @next_title = Comment.find(@commentnext.next).title
end
```

And then in your view:

```
<%= link_to @next_title, post_comment_path(@post, @commentnext.next) %>
```

Probably one of the two solutions will help you.

Answer (score 3):

From the comment: just use the same object on which you linking:

```
<%= link_to @commentnext.next.title, post_comment_path(@post, @commentnext.next) %>
```